# LinkedIn follow button not working

Tags: linkedin-api

We have the follow button in the footer of our site: https://www.holisticservices.com.au/
It used to work, but has stopped working (I don't know when).

If I'm not logged in to LinkedIn and I click the button it comes up with a popup to log in to linkedID.
If I'm already logged in then nothing happens when I click the button, not even a javascript error.
I've tried while logged in as someone who is already following and someone who is not following and both produce the same nothing result.

I'm on Chrome on windows 10

We recently change our site from http to https, could that cause a problem?

Linkedin#

Thanks in advance,
Lau

Comment: For me it also used to work till one week ago I think. It seems a problem from their side. I contacted them 3 days ago, but no feedback. I tested on more devices, and button is not working.